# 3 leaks that I am unsure of?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my app, Leaks is reporting that it is leaking in these 3 areas:

## 1

```
NSData *data = [theDictionary objectForKey:@"Item1"];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

## 2

The third line in this code

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
view3.view.frame = frame;
[self.view.superview addSubview:view3.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
                     view3.view.frame = frame;
                     frame.origin.x -= frame.size.width;
                     self.view.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
                     [self release];
                 }];
```

## 3

The first line in this code:

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:nlView.view];
    [nlView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-kWidth, 0, kWidth, kHeight)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         [nlView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight)];
                         [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(kWidth, 0, kWidth, kHeight)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [self release];
                     }];
```

I might have fixed the first one by doing [image release]; afterwards but I do not think that is the right way to do it.

For 2 and 3, I don't even see any leaks from my perspective even though Leaks says there are.

Can anyone show me where and how to fix these leaks?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that for the first question we need to see more code.  I suspect that `image` is leaking somehow, and we're not seeing the culprit code in just those two lines.

Comment: I am not really doing much more in the first one. All I am doing is getting a dictionary from an array and then I do what I show above but that is pretty much it. Release seemed to get rid of the leak in the Leaks app and it didn't cause any crashes so I am guessing I fixed it?

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you're not using ARC?  You really should.

Comment: I just have so much code in my app, it would take days for me to convert it. I just want to figure it out the old way for now.

Comment: Sure, I understand.  But the ARC conversion tool can remove all instances of `autorelease`, `release`, etc.  It's really not that hard, and if you want to disable ARC on a per-file basic it's quite easy to do.

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind. But for now, for #1 should I just release image after that line? Thats what I did, and theres no crashes so I guess that is ok right?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment.  I can't tell you unless you give me the code for how you're initializing your `image` variable.

Comment: don't know if you saw the notification but check the chat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you did not clean up nlView and view3.

Comment: How would I clean it up then properly?

Comment: Because it's code snippet so it's hard to tell, but generally it's just removing from superview and release.

Comment: So I should release view3 and nlView after I do self.view removeFromSuperview?

Comment: I would do that and also set them to nil. That should fix the leaks.

Comment: I just tried to release view3 in the completion handler and whenever I touch anything in that view, it comes up with EXC_BAD_ACCESS now, can you show me what I should do to do it properly?

Comment: Did you do `[view3.view removeFromSuperview]` first?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6278/discussion-between-tia-and-ibrad-apps)